# Is there a static data flow analysis tool for .net assemblies?

Tags: static-analysis, .net

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36982618/is-fxcop-dead-can-we-use-it-with-vs2015-edition) that CAT.NET and FxCop are dead. As far as I understand, the successor Roslyn requires a visual studio project and source code.

Is there a tool that reads in a compiled .NET program and offers an API to do static data flow analysis?

Comment: I dont know the answer to your original question, but you could try using dnSpy to decompile the application to source, then open that in Visual Studio.

Comment: Does this work in all cases? Is this workflow reliable enough to be automated? Did you do this and did the visual studio data flow analysis plugins work?

Comment: This method might work manually. I dont think it is a reliable method for automation. Usually after decompilation you will have to fix a lot of code manually to work and be compilable. I did this before manually and it worked. For automation, maybe you could take a look at dnLib to create such a project.

Comment: Do you have a specific example of the kind of analysis you want to do?

Comment: Good question. I would like to detect data dependencies between variables, arguments, return values, or data hard-coded in the binary. For example, checking if an argument for function A depends on the return value of function B, or tracking user-entered data (taint analysis).